# Spoiler-like feature in output PDF

Tags: hyperref

Assume we have some text with exercises accompanied by solutions. I would like solutions to be hidden by default, with only clickable references present. When clicked, the solutions must show up, formatted just like any other piece of the document. I don't want solutions to be located at, say, other page, but right after the corresponding exercises.

Is there any way to implement this?

p.s. not sure about the tags, please correct me and delete this p.s.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I've ocg - features in my mind. For example, the `ocgx` package. I've never used it, however

Comment: Thank you for greetings and recommendation! The ocgx package is nice, settles my search at the moment. The documentation is also quite friendly so I don't think it is worth explaining in an answer.

Comment: @WeatherReport: If you found a solution it would be nice to post it as a self-answer for future reference and other readers :-)

Comment: When this is done with slides, one actually creates a new page each time.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, amazing package.

Answer (score 3):

Following recommendations I will post a brief answer.

Christian Hupfer suggested to use `ocgx` package, to be found here https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx .

As a minimal working example consider

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\begin{document}
\switchocg{name_int}{Button}
\begin{ocg}{name_ext}{name_int}{1}
This text is either hidden or revealed
\end{ocg}
\end{document}
```

Here `\begin{ocg}` starts the *ocg (optional content group)* enviroment which is supplemented by three arguments: 1) name_ext -- name of the *ocg* to be displayed in a pdf viewer; 2) name_int -- name of the *ocg* for internal references within the tex document; 3) 1 or 0 for the default state of the *ocg* -- visible (1) or invisible (0).

`\switchocg` command takes two arguments: 1) internal name of the *ocg* that it controls and 2) the text to be displayed over the interactive button which hides/reveals text

---

**A problem:**
A serious issue is that whether this feature will work depends on the pdf viewer used. Some popular readers are supported, but some other are not.

---

**A question related to the problem:**
As explained in the op question, I would like solutions to the problems to be hidden by default. Then, if the feature works on a particular viewer everything is fine. However, if it does not, then an unfortunate reader can not see a hidden text at all. It would be appropriate to change the default state of the secret text from hidden to visible for the readers which do not support the feature. I wonder whether this might be achievable.

I can imagine something like creating a document where all such fields are visible by default. Then, include some command that automatically (say, at the beginning of the document view) executes the "button" hiding text. Then, if a reader do not support the hiding/revealing feature all the text stay visible. In contrast, for the reader capable of hiding the text it will be hidden. However, I have no idea if one can "execute" a command in the described way. Advices are quite appreciated.

Comment: `ocgx` is just one of those packages. There are others, but as I wrote in my comment to the question (above): (Unfortunately) I've not used them so far