# How can you make text only appear when it is highlighted?

Tags: fonts, formatting

I would like a way to put a "secret" message into into the output pdf that's only readable if the reader highlights the text (or something similar).

more details:

I would like the text to be invisible and only appear if the reader highlights it with their cursor.

One possibility is suggested in the comments: I could use white text (or the same color as the background). Then the message is hidden, but it's only revealed if the reader copies and pasts it. I would prefer it to be revealed when the reader selects the text (i.e., the step before copying, not sure what this is called).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Could you add some more informations?

Comment: Well you could make the text the same colour as the page? Probably white

Comment: probably this answer is good for you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270780/spoiler-like-feature-in-output-pdf

Comment: See this question : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389740/making-text-difficult-but-not-impossible-to-read/389756

Comment: When you use white text, it does become visible by selecting it, you don't need to copy it. Or at least it is dependent on your viewer. See the screenshot here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389747/23992